# How to concatenate documents from different collections in one with Mongo and the aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 4 collections in my database

(with the name of their attributes indicated in parenthesis):

**1. posts**

(with attributes  --- `CreationDate, PostId, PostTypeId and UserId`),

**2. users**

(with attributes --- `CreationDate and Id`),

**3. votes**

(with attributes --- `CreationDate, Id and UserId`)

and

**4. comments**

(with attributes --- `CreationDate, Id and UserId`).

I want to **create a collection** named **facts** that **merges** the information contained in the previous table.

It is going to be a collection formed by the collections posts, users, votes, and comments.

I mean, each document of the collection **facts** can come from the collections posts, users, votes or comments.

The **structure of the collection facts** will be:

```
                                   PostId  | PostTypeId | userId   | VoteId | CommentId
if document comes from posts     | present |  present   | present  |  null  | null     |

if document comes from users     | null    |   null     | present  |  null  | null     |

if document comes from votes     | present |   null     | present  | present | null    |

if document comes from comments  | present |   null     | present  | null    | present |
```

As you see this is going to be a very sparse collection (it is going to have a lot of null values).

How can I construct this fact collection using MongoDB and the aggregation framework?

I tried this to merge the posts and the users collections, but it did not shown any results:

```
respuestas = db.users.aggregate( [
    {'$lookup': {
        'from': "posts", 
        'localField': "Id",
        'foreignField': "OwnerUserId",
        'as': "p"}
    },
    { '$unwind': '$p'},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Id",
            "users": {
                "$push": {
                     'CreationDate' : '$CreationDate',
                     'Post' : '',
                     'PostType' : '',
                     'UserId': '$Id',
                     'VoteId' : '',
                     'CommentId' : ''
                }
            },
            "p": {
                "$push": {
                     'CreationDate' : '$p.CreationDate',
                     'Post' : '$p.Id',
                     'PostType' : '$p.PostTypeId',
                     'UserId': '$p.OwnerUserId',
                     'VoteId' : '',
                     'CommentId' : ''
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {'$limit': 20}
    ])

list(respuestas)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to do what I was looking for. I post the solution in case someone benefits from it.

```
db.users.aggregate( [
        { '$project' : 
         {
             'CreationDate' : '$CreationDate',
             'Post' : '',
             'PostType' : '',
             'UserId': '$Id',
             'VoteId' : '',
             'CommentId' : ''
         }
        },
        {'$out': "StackOverflowFacts"}
        ])

db.votes.aggregate( [
        { '$project' : 
         {
             'CreationDate' : '$CreationDate',
             'Post' : '$PostId',
             'PostType' : '',
             'UserId': '$UserId',
             'VoteId' : '$Id',
             'CommentId' : ''
         }
        },
        {'$merge' : { 'into' : "StackOverflowFacts" } }
        ])

db.comments.aggregate( [
        { '$project' : 
         {
             'CreationDate' : '$CreationDate',
             'Post' : '$PostId',
             'PostType' : '',
             'UserId': '$UserId',
             'VoteId' : '',
             'CommentId' : '$Id'
         }
        },
        {'$merge' : { 'into' : "StackOverflowFacts" } }
        ])

db.posts.aggregate( [
        { '$project' : 
         {
             'CreationDate' : '$CreationDate',
             'Post' : '$Id',
             'PostType' : '$PostTypeId',
             'UserId': '$OwnerUserId',
             'VoteId' : '',
             'CommentId' : ''
         }
        },
        {'$merge' : { 'into' : "StackOverflowFacts" } }
        ])
```

As you can see, with `$out` you can create a new collection with output of a query. Then, using `$merge`, you can add content (adding rows) to the created collection.

You can also improve the collection by creating some indexes, in order to do the queries faster: using `db.StackOverflowFacts.create_index`.

You can visualize the beginning of the collection by doing:

```
list(db.StackOverflowFacts.find().limit( 5 ))
```